# Merging by name from two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'labels' which has a many to many relationship to the table 'tokens' using the reference table 'tokens_labels'. I'm trying to put together a postgres function for merging classifiers ('classifiers' is another table) and part of it requires combining each classifier's set of tokens and set of labels. I'm trying to figure out what I should do when labels from either classifier clash in terms of the unique name-classifier_id constraint. I'd like to merge them which is made more difficult (for me as sql novice) as I'd like to maintain the many to many relationship in tokens_labels, so for the labels that get discarded as dupes, I'd like the many to many relationship to be transferred over to the label that is kept. My current code for the function is that bottom. Would love some descriptive help so I can understand what my options are for this problem. Thanks.

```
create table labels
(
    id            integer generated by default as identity
        primary key,
    name          varchar                                     not null
        constraint check_alphanumeric
            check ((name)::text ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.-]+$'::text),
    description   text
        constraint check_description_length
            check (length(description) <= 255),
    classifier_id integer                                     not null
        constraint fk_labels_classifier_id
            references classifiers
            on delete cascade,
    constraint unique_classifier_name
        unique (name, classifier_id)
);
```

```
create table tokens_labels
(
    token_id integer not null
        constraint fk_tokenslabels_token_id
            references tokens
            on delete cascade,
    label_id integer not null
        constraint fk_tokenslabels_label_id
            references labels
            on delete cascade,
    primary key (token_id, label_id)
);
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_classifiers(classifier_id_1 INT4, classifier_id_2 INT4, new_name TEXT)
RETURNS TABLE (id INT4, name TEXT, description TEXT)
language plpgsql
security definer set search_path = public
as $$
DECLARE
  new_classifier_id INT4;
  classifier_1_name TEXT;
  classifier_2_name TEXT;
BEGIN
  -- get the names of the pre-merged classifiers
  SELECT classifiers.name INTO classifier_1_name FROM classifiers WHERE classifiers.id = classifier_id_1;
  SELECT classifiers.name INTO classifier_2_name FROM classifiers WHERE classifiers.id = classifier_id_2;

  -- create new classifier
  INSERT INTO classifiers (name, description) 
  VALUES (new_name, 'This is a merge of ''' || classifier_1_name || ''' and ''' || classifier_2_name || ''' carried out on '||to_char(now(), 'FMDay FMDDth FMMonth YYYY'))
  RETURNING classifiers.id INTO new_classifier_id;
  
  -- update tokens with new classifier_id
  UPDATE tokens SET classifier_id = new_classifier_id WHERE tokens.classifier_id = classifier_id_1 OR tokens.classifier_id = classifier_id_2;

  -- update labels with new classifier_id
  UPDATE labels SET classifier_id = new_classifier_id WHERE labels.classifier_id = classifier_id_1 OR labels.classifier_id = classifier_id_2;

  -- line above will break the function if labels in either have the same name:
  -- "duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"unique_classifier_name\""

  -- delete old classifiers
  DELETE FROM classifiers WHERE classifiers.id = classifier_id_1 OR classifiers.id = classifier_id_2;

  -- return the new classifier
  RETURN QUERY SELECT classifiers.id, classifiers.name, classifiers.description  FROM classifiers WHERE classifiers.id = new_classifier_id;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).